# How to work with (SQLPlus) in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sqlcmd

I just finished the conception of a simple Java project and my client wants to use SQL Server as a Database, 
i downloaded SQL Server 2008, i tried to use SQLPlus to execute the queries but i didn't find any tutorial in the internet on how to use SQLPlus in SQL Server.
Can anyone Help me please.

Comment: SQL*Plus is for Oracle. For SQL Server you need to use `sqlcmd` or Visual Studio.

Comment: why use sqlplus. use Sqlcmd in SQL server

Comment: Thank you guys i am gonna need one more thing from you : 
where am i suppose to find it?

Comment: sqlcmd is installed with client tools, it's a command line tool, but you'll be wanting SSMS, sql server management studio, a gui ide. you can get it with a SQL Express install with advanced services.

Answer (score 1):

Check out SQLS*Plus - this is SQL*Plus for SQL server. Their web site is http://www.sqlsplus.com/